# UpdatePanel does not prevent button from reload page

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I just wanted to short [this question's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989467/how-to-open-another-tab-on-click-without-refresh-current-page-in-asp-net-web-for) by making a short prototype to test the UpdatePanel functionality to disable ASP.NET page reload on linkbutton click. I have seen this approach in questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534985/disable-page-refresh-after-button-click-asp-net). In order to test this I have created a new ASP.NET WebForms application, added an ASP LinkButton, surronded by an UpdatePanel. I have added breakpoints on both OnClick and PageLoad events, in Visual Studio .cs file. This is the code in ASP file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="OnLinkClick" runat="server">Click me, no reload, I promise!</asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the .cs file code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //page reload things...
    }

    protected void OnLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //on click thigs...
    }
```

What happens is that everytime I click on the LinkButton, the first breakpoint is triggered is the PageLoad one and then the OnClick one. I thought that using UpdatePanel will avoid this behavior.

What Am I doing wrong, or why shouldn't I expect the PageLoad not to be invoked? Is this a good way to test if the LinkButton click reloads the page?

Comment: use `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` on your button inside `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Please refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Clint B, the processing of postback events in code-behind is normal. You can test your UpdatePanel with two Labels, one inside and one outside of the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Label 1" BackColor="Aqua" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text="Label 2" BackColor="Yellow" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Update, no reload!" OnClick="OnLinkClick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The event handler of the LinkButton updates both Labels:

```
protected void OnLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    lbl2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

If the partial refresh works, the changes made to `lbl2` are visible in the page, while `lbl1` still displays its original text.

Comment: Cool, this is the answer I was looking for, thank you very much! It shows how can be tested partial reload, and it works, even though the PageLoad is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are doing a partial post back, the framework still executes the page life cycle which includes Page_Load.  But you will only be able to effect changes in the browser to the controls that are inside the update panel.

As techspider mentioned, you need to assign a post back trigger.  So your example should look like this.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="OnLinkClick" runat="server">Click me, no reload, I promise!</asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Click" /> 
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: And in this case the page will not be reloaded if one clicks on LinkButton?

Comment: Correct.  Only the things inside the update panel will be reloaded in the browser.

Comment: Since `ChildrenAsTriggers` is true by default, and since the LinkButton is inside the UpdatePanel, it is not necessary to add it explicitly to the triggers list.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when i use LinkButton inside an updatepanel, page is doing postback (page is fully refreshed in the browser) **UNLESS** i indicate an **ID** and **ClientIDMode="AutoID"** on the LinkButton control.

Comment: Found my answer.